# How to make http.redirect() to redirect automatically when executed

Tags: http, go

With this code it show me a link to click for redirect to /hello, how do i make it redirect without user interaction?

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    r := http.NewServeMux()

    r.HandleFunc("/", index)
    r.HandleFunc("/hello", hello)

    http.ListenAndServe(":80", r)
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/hello", 200)
}
func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("hello")
}
```

Comment: Try to use a http status code 302

Comment: You are passing status code `200` which is a "success" status code called "OK". Redirections are done with `3xx` status codes, like 301, 302, 307... List of common redirection codes pre-declared in Go can be found here: https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.18#StatusIMUsed. And you can read more on the topic here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections and more on statuses: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: Thanks, the standard for redirect after a successful operation (like login/register) is 308?

Comment: @mirkosailorm i would argue that the correct one is `303` for that case: https://evertpot.com/http/303-see-other . 307 is definitely not correct.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered in the comments, the standard HTTP code to be returned in case of a redirect is [303](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/303). So the redirect line should be:

```
http.Redirect(w, r, "/hello", http.StatusSeeOther)
```

Also note, using [http package](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18:src/net/http/status.go;l=9) `http.XXX` is preferred to writing HTTP codes directly